# MongoDB: Assign a single value to every key in an object

Tags: mongodb

I have some keys stored on database that need to be reset periodically.
It goes like this

```
{
  name: "Bob",
  limits:{
           one: 1000
           two: 14
           three: 19
         }
 }
```

i looked for a query that assigns values to all keys inside an object, at first I thought `$each` would help me but it has a totally different purpose.

What i want is to assign, let's say, `0` to all the keys inside `limits`

**Note:** key names from `limits` aren't constant across users and aren't always known.

It would be exactly the same as `Object.keys(limit).forEach(itm=> limit[itm]=0)` does for regular JS, but in Mongo's context

Answer (score 0):

You're halfway through:

You can iterate the collection and apply the `forEach` method for every cursor document

```
db.collection.find().forEach(function(d) {
    Object.keys(d.limits).forEach(item=> d.limits[item]=0); 
    db.collection.save(d);
})
```

Caution: this can be very slow.

Comment: yeah, that would be REALLY slow, even on a relatively small database like mine with ~50k documents, totally not scalable. That's why i'm after a solution on mongo itself, for now i'm sticking with a rather "creative" solution that is keeping track of all new keys added and cycling through them with updateMany, which is considerably fast.